# Save collapse state in localstorage

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I currently have dynamic list-item /w collapse rendered from an API.

Now I'm trying to save the state of the collapse (true or false/ Open closed) in localstorage so that when the page get refreshed I't will remember what collapse have been opend by the user.

How do I save the dynamic state in the localstorage?

You can see my code below

**Dynamic state change and localstorage save**

```
handleClick=(e, item)=>{

    this.setState({

      [item.id + 'Open'] : !this.state[item.id +'Open']

    })

       // store item details and jwt token in local storage to keep item logged in between page refreshes
       localStorage.setItem('currentopentab', JSON.stringify(item));
       currentUserSubject.next(item);

       return item;

  };
```

**List item**

```
<List
            component="nav"
            subheader={<ListSubheader component="div">Waiting for order</ListSubheader>}
            className={classes.root}
          >
          {
              this.state.ordersWaiting.map((item, index) =>{
                return (
                <div key={index}>
                 {console.log('item',item)}
                  <ListItem button className={classes.orderheader} >
                    <div className={classes.expandContainer} onClick={((e) => this.handleClick(e, item))}>
                      <ListItemIcon>
                        <InboxIcon />
                      </ListItemIcon>
                      <ListItemText inset primary={item.userName}  secondary={item.timeStamp}/>

                      {this.state[item.id + 'Open'] ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                    </div>
                    <Fab color="secondary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.fabButton}>
                      <AddIcon onClick={((e) => this.prepareOrder(e, item))} />
                    </Fab>
                  </ListItem>
                  <Collapse in={this.state[item.id + 'Open'] } timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                    { item.order.map((products, index) =>{
                      return (<ListItem key={index} button className={classes.nested}>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                          <StarBorder />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                            <ListItemText inset primary={products.qty + ' x ' + products.product} />            
                      </ListItem>
                      )
                      }  
                      )}
                    </List>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is local storage class I created

**LocalStorageService.js**

```
class LocalStorageService {

    constructor() {
        this.uid = new Date;
        this.storage = {};
        this.storeable = false;

        this.hasStorage();

        if (this.storeable) {
            this.storage = window.localStorage;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify that device has storage 
     */
    hasStorage() {
        try {
            (this.storage = window.localStorage).setItem(this.uid, this.uid);
            this.storeable = this.storage.getItem(this.uid) !== this.uid;
            this.storage.removeItem(this.uid);
            this.storeable && (this.storage = false);
        } catch (exception) {}
    }

    /**
     * Return true if key exists
     */
    has(key) {
        return  !_.isNull(this.get(key))
    }

    /**
     * Get item from storage
     */  
    get(key) {
        return this.storage.getItem(key);
    }

    /**
     * Remove item from storage
     */
    remove(key) {
        this.storage.removeItem(key);
    }

    /**
     * Save item to storage
     */
    put(key,item) {
        this.storage.setItem(key,item);
    }

    /**
     *Update item in storage
     */
    update(key,obj) {
        this.remove(key);
        this.save(key,obj)
    }

    /**
     * Object to JSON string 
     */
    stringify(obj) {
        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Parse JSON string back to JS
     */
    parse(key) {
        return JSON.parse(this.get(key));
    }

    /**
     * Save object to storage 
     */
    save(key,obj) {
        if (this.storeable) {
            try {
                this.storage.setItem(key,this.stringify(this.setItem(obj)));
            } catch(e) {
                this.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }



}

export default LocalStorageService;
```

To use it in your own class you import.

**yourClassExample.js**

```
    import LocalStorageService from 'LocalStorageService';

    class YourOwnClass {

        constructor() {
            this._storage = new LocalStorageService();
        }

        storeItem(storageKey,storageData) {
            if (this._storage.isStoreable() && !this._storage.has(storageKey)) {
                 this._storage.save(storageKey,storageData);
            }
        }

    }
```

You can also make it global

```
    import LocalStorageService from 'LocalStorageService';

    window.$storage = new LocalStorageService();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it: I set an object with `id` and `open` status so that it makes me easy to track for each item.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

// this is your items array with many objects, I am using only id as for the illustration here
const items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      itemState: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const itemState = localStorage.getItem("itemState");
    itemState
      ? this.setState({ itemState: JSON.parse(itemState) })
      : this.setItemState();
  }

  handleClick(id) {
    const itemState = [...this.state.itemState];
    itemState.forEach(item => item.id === id && (item.open = !item.open));

    this.setState({ itemState });
    localStorage.setItem("itemState", JSON.stringify(itemState));
  }

  setItemState() {
    let itemState = [];
    // this items is what you fetched from the backend
    // setting id and open flag to track the open status for each item
    items.forEach(item => {
      itemState.push({ id: item.id, open: false });
    });
    this.setState({ itemState });
    localStorage.setItem("itemState", JSON.stringify(itemState));
  }

  isItemOpen(id) {
    const { itemState } = this.state;
    const currentItem = itemState.filter(item => item.id === id)[0];
    return currentItem ? currentItem["open"] : false;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4)}</pre>
        {items.map(item => {
          return this.isItemOpen(item.id) ? (
            <div id={item.id}>
              ID: {item.id} <br />
              Open: Open <br />
              Other content <br />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)}> Change</button>
              <hr />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div>
              {" "}
              The Div with id {item.id} is Closed now{" "}
              <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.id)}> Change</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```